# How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?

Tags: c#

I want to create a simple editor like [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) with simple functionality... I need to color a specific word in the rich text box area. How can I do that?

For example: when the user write these word, I want to color them to the blue color. These words are: `for`, `while`, `if`, `try`, etc.

How can I make the richtextbox to select a specific word and then color them?
And, if I want to make a comment and color everything after the `//`, how is that done in the richtextbox?

How do I number the line in the text box, so I can now the line number when I'm coding in my editor?

Comment: The line-number thing should be a separate question (please don't 'stack' questions). Most likely it won't be easily possible with `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Try Fast Color Text Box(https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox) it is more then a syntax highlighter

Comment: Even available as Nuget(https://www.nuget.org/packages/FCTB/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's some code you can build on in order to achieve the functionality you want.

```
private void ColourRrbText(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    Regex regExp = new Regex("\b(For|Next|If|Then)\b");

    foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(rtb.Text))
    {
        rtb.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
        rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

The CodeProject article [Enabling syntax highlighting in a RichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10675/Enabling-syntax-highlighting-in-a-RichTextBox) shows how to use RegEx in a RichTextBox to perform syntax highlighting. Specifically, look at the `SyntaxRichtTextBox.cs` for the implementation.

Comment: This will highlight the part of word, if i type _Forever_ it will highlight  **For**ever

Comment: Thanks alex, but by the time i found a workaround  ` string kewyords = "For|Next|If|Then";
            kewyords = kewyords.Replace("|", "\b|\b");
`

Comment: Btw if you are calling it on keyPress event then you need to add                  `rtb.DeselectAll();`
`rtb.SelectionStart = rtbCommand.Text.Length;` to deselect the text and move the cursor to the end

Answer (score 4):

In general, you have to work on the selection in RichTextBox. You can manipulate the current selection using the `Find` method or using `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties. Then you can change properties of selected text using `SelectionXXX` properties. For example, `SelectionColor` would set the color of current selection, etc. So you have to parse text in richtextbox and then select part of texts and change their properties as per your requirements.

Writing a good text editor using RichTextBox can be quite cumbersome. You should use some library such as [Scintilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scintilla_%28editing_component%29) for that. Have a look at [ScintillaNet](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/), a .NET wrapper over Scintilla.

Comment: I will take a look on Scintilla. and i was asking for these questions since, I don't know before that there is a library that can do this job & i hope it is easy to understand and works with it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that Notepad++ uses [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/)?

You actually do not have to reinvent the wheel by going through all the trouble as there is a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) port of Scintilla named [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) which you can freely embed in your application as the source code editor :)

But to answer your question, there are few parts that you need to understand

1. Finding what to color
2. When to color
3. How to color
4. For the first part, there may be different approaches, but I think using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) would be a good choice. I am sorry, but I don't know regular expressions much so I cannot help you in that case.
5. When to color is very crucial and if you do it wrong, your application will suffer a heavy performance penalty. I suggest you refer to [XPath Visualizer](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com) which was done by our own Stack Overflow member, Cheeso. Take a look at the source on how the coloring of the syntax was done. But if you ScintillaNET, everything would be taken care of. Anyway, I really can't seem to find this documentation where he clearly showed how the coloring of the text was done. I would most definitely post it here if I find it.
6. The third question I think is covered by VinayC. But basically you use [SelectionColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor.aspx) along with [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx).

Comment: Ok, I will take a look on Scintilla. and I hope that it is easy to understand it...

Answer (score 0):

here is a [good link on c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/duncanharris/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP112012005050840AM/SyntaxHighlightInRichTextBoxP1.aspx)   website on basic richtextbox syntax highlighting. I assume that you and any one visiting this page for similar problem want to do it for learning purpose. But if any one wants to do it for some making some comercial level IDE then it must use [scintilla](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/documentation) or some similar. 
An other approach for this is to directly [change the RTF of the richtextbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15038/C-Formatting-Text-in-a-RichTextBox-by-Parsing-the). Look in codeproject.com there are lot of articles similar to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with that and here is my solution, beats me why it has to be done like this, but it works:

```
            // position on end of control...
            richTextBox.UpdateLayout();
            richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
            richTextBox.UpdateLayout();

            // ...then select text and it will be position on top of control.
            richTextBox.Focus();
            richTextBox.Selection.Select(foundRange.Start, foundRange.End);
            richTextBox.BringIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Vb.net implementation

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Private Sub formatString()
  Dim rg =New Regex("\b(for|while|if|try)\b")
  Dim m As Match

 For Each m In rg.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)
   RichTextBox1.Select(m.Index,m.Length)
   RichTextBox1.SelectionColor=Color.Green 
 Next

End Sub
```