# C# - RichTextBox change color of certain words

Tags: c#, richtextbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it)

I don't really have any code to show, because I don't know :(. I have a server that outputs information with tags. For example:

```
15:44 [INFO] Loaded Properties
15:45 [ERROR] Properties not found
```

How do I look in the richtextbox and make all **ERROR** tags red, **INFO** tags GREEN, etc.?

Comment: The accepted answer on the post I suggested as a duplicate looks to be a very good way of doing what you want

Comment: Thanks but the Regex doesn't work - whats the namespace?

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx

Comment: Right click on the method, select resolve. VS will pop it in it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do what you want:

```
for(int i=0; i<rtb.Lines.Length; i++) 
{ 
   string text = rtb.Lines[i];
   rtb.Select(rtb.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i), text.Length); 
   rtb.SelectionColor = colorForLine(text); 
} 

private Color colorForLine(string line)
{
    if(line.Contains("[INFO]", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) return Color.Green;
    if(line.Contains("[ERROR]", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) return Color.Red;

    return Color.Black;
}
```

**Edit:** Changed `StartsWith` to `Contains`

Comment: @AlexOgden try with `Contains` instead of `StartsWith`

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in colorForLine and see if the conditions get hit

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
//will select characters form index 0 to 9
richTextBox1.Select(0, 10);

//will set the characters from 0 to 9 to red
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Other answer already shows that + it is `SelectionColor` not `SelectionColour`

Comment: @EddardStark - or just English as it is known