# Change font of text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

My text is in a richtextbox:

```xml
<Parag1 Level="One">
First text of parag1. Second text of parag1.
</Parag1>
<Parag2 Level="Two">
First text of parag2. Second text of parag2.
</Parag2>
<Parag3 Level="Footer">
First text of parag3. Second text of parag3.
</Parag3>
<Parag4 Level="Three">
First text of parag4. Second text of parag4.
</Parag4>
```

I want change color font & text color of text :

1- For tags -> font name = Tahoma , size= 10,color=red

Example : `<Parag1 Level="One">` Or `</Parag1>`

2- For Text between tags that tag's level is not Footer -> font name = Arial , size= 12,color=black

Example : `First text of parag1. Second text of parag1.` Or `First text of parag4. Second text of parag4.`

3- For Text between tags that tag's level is Footer -> font name = Microsoft Sans Serif, size= 8,color=blue

Example : `First text of parag3. Second text of parag3.`

How can I do it in c# ?(Changes font of all text at once!)

Comment: Please don't add "C#" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to select parts of text and use `SelectionColor`and `SelectionFont`properties.
Everything is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-a-text-from-the-richtextbox-then-color-it).

Hope this helps

Now for your other question, if you mean how to change the font and color of the text inserted while the program is running, try this.

```
         private void someTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
         {
           this.someTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue; 
           // Same goes for font and other properties
         }
```

I don't have time to test it so I don't know how it will act with the other colors you previously set.

Comment: Thank's PhaDaPhunk. How can I change font(fontname, size, style, color) of part of text that insert between text of richtextbox ? But font of other parts of text don't change.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand what you're asking.
Could you update your question and provide an example?

Comment: Thank's from you. Please visit this link and replay it:[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002827/insert-paragraph-between-text-of-richtextbox-and-change-font-and-color-of-added)

Comment: I'll try and find an answer to this question.