# Numbered Musical Nodes into RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, richtextbox

Jianpu nodes are something like this:

[image]

So I want to make an application where user can specify the nodes and the output is the sound of the nodes

[image]

My problem is that I don't know how to display the nodes like the above in a `RichTextBox`.

Comment: Are there unicode characters to display these characters?

Comment: Just curious: how did you come to the conclusion that you want to use a RichTextBox at all?

Comment: the first idea to come to my mind is using richTextBox. but i kinda confused right now, maybe i'll just use painting

Comment: @ThomasW. what do you think about using richTextBox, is it wrong?

Comment: No no, RichTextBox is fine. Even better than doing anything else on your own. Just use the fonts suggested by TaW. But you must have known that a RichTextBox usually contains text, and you would need some text which looks like graphics.

Comment: i have tried his solution but as he said "may not work without problems", i'm having a problem that is not every \u1D177 type of thing (what should i say this) work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There some fonts out there but you will have to test their quality.

Here is one, that is for [Jianpu notes](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CipherMusic), more details [here](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CipherMusic), but may not work without problems..

Here is a solution for [Erhu Players & Jianpu Readers](http://simperhu.weebly.com/)

And creating a set of notes with a free font maker is also an option.

And finally you might do it all in .Net, including all the painting, but try the fonts first!

Comment: yes, i'll try using font first, my last option is to do painting, but it will take more time. thanks for your answer

Comment: Link 1 (Jianpu notes) and 2 (here) are the same URL. Did you want to provide different URLs?

Comment: Whoops, thanks. I thought they were different but I was mixing things up (the top and the graphics at the bottom). Here is a [Demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjItHceiG8c) of the SimpErhu software. And in the bottom of this [forum thread](http://musescore.org/en/node/12338) there are more links..

Answer (score 2):

There is Unicode 0307 (combining dot above) (looks like 1̇ ) or Unicode 0358 (combining dot above right) (looks like 1͘ ) but they don't perform very well for your task in my opinion. I think 0301 (combining acute accent) (looks like 1́ ) is better, although not very accurate.

For the bottom part 0316 (combining grave accent below) (looks like 1̖ ) is not very nice. You can try 0323 (combining dot below) (looks like 1̣).

You add the unicode characters after the normal letter and you can combine many of them (like 1̣́). Note that the results may vary among different types of fonts. The fonts I experience to support Unicode best are Arial and Times New Roman. I usually take Word, go to  insert/symbol and try what looks best.

For the best results I recommend looking for a specialized font that has all the tones built in. Or create such a font by yourself. CorelDraw was able (in Version 6) to create fonts. I guess it still can in newer versions.

Comment: well if i want to use custom font, the next question , how to display the font into richTextBox then?

Comment: @AltianoGerung: See [Change font of text in richtextbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983732/change-font-of-text-in-richtextbox). The links provided by TaW also explain how to combine the characters.