# Issue with Spell Checker as you type. How to Change font for only part of text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox

I tried implementing the Hunspell spell-checker library to check my spelling as I type in my notepad application using c#. It seems to work fine, but when a misspelled word appears the entire RichTextBox gets underlined.

```
public void spellchecker()
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
    {       
        using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_US.dic"))
        {
            String sentence = GetRichTextBox().Text;
            foreach (string item in sentence.Split(' '))
            {
                bool correct = hunspell.Spell(item);
                if (correct == false)

                {
                    GetRichTextBox().Font = new Font(GetRichTextBox().Font, FontStyle.Underline);
                }
                else {
                    GetRichTextBox().Font = new Font(GetRichTextBox().Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                }   

            }           
        }
    }));
}
```

The error appears to be in the line:

```
GetRichTextBox().Font = new Font(GetRichTextBox().Font, FontStyle.Underline);
```

So when I replace it with:

```
item.Font = new Font(item.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
```

..an error appears saying "String Does not contain definition for font". I cannot get the misspelled word to be underlined individually.

Comment: `GetRichTextBox().Font` changes the font of the entire RichTextBox. `item.Font` is invalid because item is simply a string that has no `Font` property. Your question should be something like _"How to change the font for only part of the text of RichTextBox"_.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: This is a Windows Forms Application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change font of text in richtextbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983732/change-font-of-text-in-richtextbox)

Comment: "Doesn't work" means nothing. Edit your question and show what you have tried with the help of the other question along with any error messages you might have.

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't split the string by `' '` because this will treat "Hello;world", for example, as one word. You should use Regex to find words in the string. Use this pattern `\w+`.

Second, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9983927/4934172) to the linked question, you can use the [`SelectionColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectioncolor) and [`SelectionFont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionfont) properties to change the style of text *after selecting the target text*.

This should work:

```
Font fnt = richTextBox1.Font;
Color color;

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, @"\w+"))
{
    string word = match.Value;
    if (!hunspell.Spell(word))
    {
        fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Underline);
        color = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        fnt = new Font(fnt.FontFamily, fnt.Size, FontStyle.Regular);
        color = Color.Black;
    }

    richTextBox1.Select(match.Index, match.Length);        // Selecting the matching word.
    richTextBox1.SelectionFont = fnt;                      // Changing its font and color
    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = color;
    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = richTextBox1.TextLength; // Resetting the selection.
    richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Result:

[image: RichTextBox highlighting]

Note: I used `if (word.length < 5)` for testing, you can apply your own condition as shown in the code above.

Hope that helps.