# Don't highlight newline characters when selecting with TextPointers

Tags: c#, wpf, newline, richtextbox, highlight

So, I have a `RichTextBox` (shown below) which has a monospaced font, and must have the same number of characters on each line. Doing this requires inserting a `\n` newline character after every `x` characters in the string that feeds the box.

I also have an algorithm that allows the cursor to move around with the press of the arrow keys, selecting individual characters as it moves. When the cursor covers a word in the box though, it should highlight the whole word.

Problem: When a word spans mutliple lines, there is an empty space following the final character of the first line, which I assume is caused by the `\n` character.

**How can I make the `RichTextBox.Selection.Select()` not highlight these blank spaces?** I can strip the selection of the character when parsing and such, but I need to be able to not highlight this blank space.

EDIT: An acceptable alternative would be making the newlines uneccessary. As in, to somehow fix the `RichTextBox` so that it has always 12 characters on each line, but this is not ideal since I'd like to keep it easy to resize the window.

**UPDATE: It seems that decreasing the width of the text column within the XAML has decreased the size of the highlight that goes over the edge, but has not eliminated it completely. I cannot decrease the width any more without causing text to wrap.**

[image: Example of Problem]

Comment: I see one principal problem with these new lines (carriage returns): how do you know that a particular carriage return is there to limit output length and you need to span the selection to the next line, or it is a carriage return that is just part of text, in which case you probably won't span the highlight?

Comment: Do you stripe out carriage returns and line feeds from the original text before fitting it into the text box?

Comment: No. There are none. The original text is one contiguous string. I append a `\r` every 12 characters.

Comment: Would enabling WordWrap achieve what you want?

Comment: Can you store the positions of \r characters in the string in a list and then exclude them every time you use RichTextBox.Selection.Select()? Maybe if you showed us the code of your algorithm would be helpful

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I can strip the characters when I get the contents of the selection for processing, but for displaying, I don't believe you can select discontinuous regions of text.

Comment: Do you need specific features provided by RichTextBox, or can it be a different control?

Comment: It *could* be a different control, but it would be a pain in the ass to switch, and who knows if I'll need specific features later on. Things always change

Comment: @dymanoid the WPF RichTextBox is *not* based on the Win32 one already. It uses flow documents instead of RTF.

Comment: @Wazner It turns out you cannot *disable* wordwrap in a `RichTextBox`. Go figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured out that the problem is not specifically related to the `\n` character.

I'm still not entirely sure what caused it, but I fixed it like this:

After playing around and noticing that changing the width of the column had an effect on the width of the bad highlighted area, I tried decreasing it away. Problem was, this caused text to wrap.

So I figured, okay, I'll just disable WordWrap for the `RichTextBox`, right? Wrong. WPF does not allow us to disable this.

I needed a way to achieve the effect of disabling WordWrap, so after doing some reading, I saw that I could set the `FlowDocument`'s `Width` property to a very large number so that the text would never wrap. Even to do this, I then had to go and disable the scroll bar.

So then, I had the effect of wordwrap disabled and I was able to continue decreasing the width of the `RichTextBox` until the bad space was invisible, if not gone.

So, problem solved, but I'm still left with one question: Why does Microsoft hate me?

Comment: Windows have the line end as `\r\n`, not `\r` not `\n`, you should use `Environment.NewLine` for breaking the word across the lines. Nobody hate you, you've created the problem from nothing

Comment: I can confirm that the problem still exists if I use both characters. That was what I originally was using.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try to split the word with '\n'. then loop through each split and pass it to the RichTextBox.Selection.Select().

Something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it)