# How to select text from WPF RichTextBox then replace and color it

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make my WPF RichTextBox appear like a coding page.

I marked some words to determind it's a keyword or a string,... Now I have text like this:

`<@$keyword>int<keyword$@> sum;`

`sum = 1;`

`Console.WriteLine(<@$string>"{0}"<string$@>,sum);`

The result should be like this:

```
int sum;
sum = 1;
Console.WriteLine("{0}",sum);
```

But "int" is blue and "{0}" is pink.

Here is my xaml RichTextBox code:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding codeContent}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
```

My question refer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it)
but it not seem to solve my problem.

Because my WPF RichTextBox built up with FlowDocument inside, we can't get the content text by things like `String st = myRichtextBox.Text`, we need to use TextRange to get the text inside it: `TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart,rtb.Document.ContentEnd)` .

But another problem is it get the whole text, not get a part of content text that I want. Example: RichTextBox rtb contain:`<@$keyword>int<keyword$@> sum;sum = 1;Console.WriteLine(<@$string>"{0}"<string$@>,sum);` and I want to get just `<@$keyword>int<keyword$@>`and `<@$string>"{0}"<string$@>` and edit it not the whole text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it)

Comment: Yes, it's the same question but different technic, I'm using **WPF RichTextBox** which not allow you to get the contain text that easy.
I found it we can use TextRange to get all the text and edit it. But how can I get the exactly text to edit it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957441/richtextbox-wpf-does-not-have-string-property-text This will do the trick

Comment: @efekctive that's how to get the whole text inside it. But I just want to get a small part of the text. Example: `<@$keyword>int<keyword$@>` but not `<@$keyword>int<keyword$@> sum;sum = 1;
Console.WriteLine(<@$string>"{0}"<string$@>,sum);`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, I'm working on it and will put down the answer if I found it

Answer (score 1):

```
TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart,rtb.Document.ContentEnd)
```

tr.Text gives you the plain string of the contents. Now you have an string to use with regex/substrings following:

[How to select text from the RichTextBox and then color it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it)