# Why does the Notepad++ [NULL] character not paste?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, notepad++

I am new to this site, and I don't know if I am providing enough info - I'll do my best =)

If you use Notepad++, then you will know what I am talking about -- When a user loads a `.exe` into Notepad++, the `NUL` / `\x0` character is replaced by `NULL`, which has a black background, and white text. I tried pasting it into Visual Studio, hoping to obtain the same output, but it just pasted some spaces...

Does anyone know if this is a certain key-combination, or something? I would like to put the `NULL` character in replacement of `\x0`, just like Notepad++ =)

[image: This picture contains the NUL character I want :)]

Comment: Use a hex editor instead.

Comment: Well, I am creating a `Text Editor`, and I am wondering how I would be able to replace `NUL` bytes with the same character `Notepad++` uses :)

Comment: I don't want to use a `hex` editor -- I am trying to create my own type of app =)

Comment: I see. Read my answer below. See if that helps.

Comment: It is _extremely_ not advised to put 0x00 bytes in a text. It is not a valid character in any encoding system, and c/c++ programs even automatically consider it the end of a string.
It is _also_ extremely not advised to open an exe file in a text editor. Just use a hex editor, sheesh. You can't do anything good there anyway.

Comment: Is this an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Perhaps you can explain what you are really trying to do rather than asking why your attempt at a solution is not working.

Comment: Well, I want to display the `NUL` byte in my `RichTextBox`, the same way Notepad++ does :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepad++ is a rich text editor unlike your regular notepad. It can display custom graphics so common in all modern text editors. While reading a file whenever notepad++ encounters the ASCII code of a null character then instead of displaying nothing it adds the string "NULL" to the UI setting the text background colour to black and text colour to white which is what you are seeing. You can show any custom style in your rich text editor too.

***NOTE:*** This is by no means an efficient solution. I'm clearly traversing a read string 2 times just to take benefit of already present methods. This can be done manually in a single pass. It is just to give a hint about how you can do it. Also I wrote the code carefully but haven't ran it because I don't have the tools at the moment. I apologise for any mistakes let me know I'll update it

**Step 1** : Read a text file by line (line ends at '\n') and replace all instances of null character of that line with the string `"NUL"` using the `String.Replace()`. Finally append the modified text to your `RichTextBox`.

**Step 2** : Re traverse your read line using `String.IndexOf()` finding start indexes of each "NUL" word. Using these indexed you select text from `RichTextBox` and then style that selected text using `RichTextBox.SelectionColor` and `RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor`

`richTextBoxCursor` basically just represents the start index of each line in `RichTextBox`

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt" , Encoding.UTF8); 
int richTextBoxCursor = 0;

while (!sr.EndOfStream){

   richTextBoxCursor = richTextBox.TextLength;

   string line = sr.ReadLine();
   line = line.Replace(Convert.ToChar(0x0).ToString(), "NUL");
   richTextBox.AppendText(line);

   i = 0;

   while(true){
     i = line.IndexOf("NUL", i) ;
     if(i == -1) break;

     // This specific select function select text start from a certain start index to certain specified character range passed as second parameter
     // i is the start index of each found "NUL" word in our read line
     // 3 is the character range because "NUL" word has three characters
     richTextBox.Select(richTextBoxCursor + i , 3);

     richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.White;
     richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Black;

     i++;
   }

}
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Well it depends what tools are you using ? WinForms, WPF or something else ?

Comment: I am using `Windows Forms`, and I am programming with my `RichTextBox`, using `Visual Studio`

Comment: See my edited answer. Main thing is to select each "NUL" word in `RichTextBox` using `RichTextBox.Select()` method and color its text color and background color using `RichTextBox.SelectionColor` and `RichTextBox.SelectionBackColor`

Comment: You can also follow these links that make use of Regex to make your life easier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707120/how-to-select-text-from-the-richtextbox-and-then-color-it , https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10675/Enabling-syntax-highlighting-in-a-RichTextBox , https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/search-and-highlight-text-in-rich-textbox/

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ may use custom or special fonts to show these particular characters. This behavior also may not appropriate for all text editors. So, they don't show them. 
If you want to write a text editor that visualize these characters, you probably need to implement this behavior programmatically. Seeing notepad++ source can be helpful If you want.

Comment: I checked it, but it is written in C++ :( I don't know C++ very well..

Comment: It's not going to be an easy task. To do this, you may need to do a lot of low-level programming and even create custom text box control, which needs a lot of effort!.

Answer (score 2):

## Text editor

As far as I know in order to make Visual Studio display non printable characters you need to install an extension from the marketplace at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com.

One such extension, which I have neither tried nor recomend - I just did a quick search and this is the first result - is 
[Invisible Character Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaneRay.InvisibleCharacterVisualizer).

Having said that, copy-pasting binaries is a risky business.

---

You may try *Edit > Advanced > View White Space* first.

---

## Binary editor

To really see what's going on you could use the VS' binary editor: File->Open->(Open with... option)->Binary Editor -> OK

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: So, that being said, if I did just paste the `NUL` symbol into Visual Studio, I would still get the same output in a label, even if the string was made up of spaces? I pasted the `NUL` bytes, and I am getting random spaces instead -- Will that affect anything? Or will it just print spaces? :D

Comment: I'd say that the only way to be sure if the characters are preserved is to use the binary editor.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question.

It's a symbolic representation of `00H` double byte.

You're copying and pasting the values. Notepad++ is showing you symbols that replace the representation of those values (because you configured it to do so in that IDE).

Comment: But, how can I display the SAME symbols? Using the `00H` double `byte`?

Comment: In regards to your replicating the concept, would have to research into what notepad++ is doing - since that feature isn't restricted to specific fonts as it relates to styles.  The Glpyh isn't likely to be in a character map of the font used by the rest of the page, that is.

Comment: Hmm.. How would I do this? I see `Notepad++` on `Github`, but I have no idea what's going on there -- I know `C#`like crazy, but `C++`, a mystery..

Comment: well.. with just brief review of the code, it's possible they are using "transliteration" as a means. charMap source and charMap destination.  Typically a concept for languages, but could apply to this feature.

Comment: :) I will look into that after I am done checking out `Invisible Character See-er` or something :D

Comment: actually.. they are handling everything about the rendering in the GTK, to include creating fonts.  [github link](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/scintilla/gtk/PlatGTK.cxx#L74).  I'd say, perhaps review the GTK source there and see how much C++ font rending concepts you can absorb from it, then perhaps pose a question to the C++ members of this community in your earnest attempt to handle such a feature.

Comment: - Actually, I have an idea - Could I just, scan for the `\x0` `NUL` bytes, and then obviously replace them with `NUL`, but I would change the selection backcolor of the `NUL` bytes to black, and the selection color to white. That could work? :D